# installation of patch supee-5344 for magento 1.5.1.0

Tags: patches

I am using `magento 1.5.1.0` and I want to install patch  `SUPEE-5344`. When I check the download page of `magentocommerce.com` I can only find the patch for `Magento-CE-v1.4.0.x-1.5.0.x`

Will this version support version 1.5.1 ? or does it only support up to version 1.5.0.x ?

Thanks for your input

Comment: Three files are repaired in that patch => `app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php`, `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php` and `lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php`. Running a diff shows there were major changes between 1.5.0.1 and 1.5.1.0. I didn't check to see if there were changes between 1.5.1.0 and 1.6.2.0. If you could go decompress those two install archives, you could diff the files to see if they're alike.

Comment: You should upgrade your Magento store anyway, because I think only _major_ security issues are fixed with a patch also available for older versions. Smaller security issues are only fixed with new versions.

Answer (score 4):

The patch for 1.5.1.0 was erroneously left out of the list (yes, I find this alarming too). I've opened a ticket to have the patch added, but in the meantime I can email this to anyone who would like it. Just let me know (As a moderator I can see your email) or send me a request at ben.marks@magento.com.

Comment: Thank you for thanking me, but please know that I think we should be doing a better job at communicating these kind of differences than we are.

Answer (score 3):

The patch is now available from the official download page. When you download the patch SUPEE-5344 for CE 1.5.1.0 the filename is `PATCH_SUPEE-5390_CE_1.5.1.0_v1.sh`. Don't wonder, that's okay. Also see [SUPEE-5344 - Addresses a potential remote code execution exploit](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/57659/supee-5344-addresses-a-potential-remote-code-execution-exploit) for a list of the filename in all versions.