# SUPEE-5344 - Addresses a potential remote code execution exploit

Tags: security, patches, magento-1.4, magento-1.5, ce-1.4.2.0

What will be the major changes in the files after installation of [**patch SUPEE-5344**](https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/) for Magento 1.4.2.0? I mean that any particular files permission changes something like that...
Please help me for the same.

Comment: This is a patch, check the code?

Comment: I checked those files.But I didn't understand code.Three files are updated by this patch app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php, app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php and lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php.

Comment: Please note that if you are running Magento CE 1.4.2.0 then the patch you should use is SUPEE-5388

Comment: @ForMat But in the magento download it is mentioned as SUPEE-5344. please check the link http://www.magentocommerce.com/download

Comment: Once you select your Magento CE 1.4.2.0 version and hit the download button you will see that you will get another patch file (examine the link in your browser). Also check out the list of files for this patch in the answer below by @Matthias

Comment: The UK hosting service NuBlue has also backported the fix in patch format for 1.3.x.x -> [available here.](https://www.nublue.co.uk/blog/magento-remote-code-execution-bug-patches-for-pre-1-6-versions/) Run on a test server first for function.

Comment: The details of the exploit have now been disclosed by the Checkpoint Team: [Analyzing the Magento Vulnerability (Updated) - by Netanel Rubin, Check Point Malware & Vulnerability Research Group posted 2015/04/20](http://blog.checkpoint.com/2015/04/20/analyzing-magento-vulnerability/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to understand it. No functionality changes and the API changes are irrelevant for at least 99.99% of developers. If you don't understand it, you are one of those. Just apply it. File permissions are not relevant, as far as I see it prevents an SQL injection through certain requests to the web service.

#### Specifically for Magento 1.4, the following files have been changed:

- `app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php`

  Do not use URL parameter `forwarded` for forwarded requests, but property `internaly_forwarded` that cannot be set from outside
- `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php`

  Provide getters and setters for this property
- `lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php`

  Remove `field_expr` feature from collection conditions. I tried to use that once and it wasn't useful as it is anyway. The core code does not use it anyway as well. So it's safe to say that this won't affect any extensions/customizations.

The patch file for Magento 1.4 up to 1.5.0.1 is `PATCH_SUPEE-5388_CE_1.4.0.0-1.5.0.1_v1.sh` (Note that the number is `5388`, but it is the same patch as `5344` for Magento 1.8 and 1.9)

Comment: I value your contribution here, but only the last sentence gives an answer to the OP's question. IMO just saying he doesn't need to understand goes against the whole idea SE stands for, to question things ;)

Comment: Ignorantly running bash scripts on your machine/server isn't the brightest idea either.

Answer (score 15):

As an example, these files are affected in EE 1.13/1.14:

```
app/code/core/Enterprise/Logging/Block/Adminhtml/Grid/Filter/Ip.php
app/code/core/Enterprise/Logging/Block/Adminhtml/Index/Grid.php
app/code/core/Enterprise/Logging/Model/Resource/Event/Collection.php
app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Model/Observer.php
lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
```

While it looks like some quite important classes are modified the changes are quite small and won't affect most of the shops as @fschmengler said. The attack vector is pretty complex and requires a complex combination of actions. As far as is known no shop has been compromised yet. According to Magento you should check if unknown files can be found in the web server document root directory.

File permissions are not changed.

Here is a list of the filenames for the different patches in case somebody is confused because of the patch number:

- **CE 1.4.0.x – 1.5.0.x**

  PATCH_SUPEE-5388_CE_1.4.0.0-1.5.0.1_v1.sh
- **CE 1.5.1.0**

  PATCH_SUPEE-5390_CE_1.5.1.0_v1.sh
- **CE 1.6.0.x**

  PATCH_SUPEE-5341_CE_1.6.0.0_v1.sh
- **CE 1.6.1.x – 1.6.2.x**

  PATCH_SUPEE-5346_CE_1.6.1.0_v1.sh
- **CE 1.7.x**

  PATCH_SUPEE-5345_CE_1.7.0.2_v1.sh
- **CE 1.8.x – 1.9.x**

  PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1.sh
- **EE 1.7.0.0 – 1.10.0.2**

  PATCH_SUPEE-5388_EE_1.7.0.0_to_1.10.0.2_v1-2015-02-12-06-15-02.sh
- **EE 1.10.1.x**

  PATCH_SUPEE-5390_EE_1.10.1.x_v1-2015-02-12-06-25-09.sh
- **EE 1.11.0.x**

  PATCH_SUPEE-5341_EE_1.11.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-04-08-59.sh
- **EE 1.11.1.0 – 1.12.1.0**

  PATCH_SUPEE-5346_EE_1.11.1.0_v1-2015-02-10-04-13-55.sh
- **EE 1.12.0.x**

  PATCH_SUPEE-5345_EE_1.12.0.2_v1-2015-02-10-04-17-49.sh
- **EE 1.13.x – 1.14.x**

  PATCH_SUPEE-5344_EE_1.14.1.0_v1-2015-02-10-04-20-13.sh

**[UPDATE]** A patch for 1.5.1.0 is now available.

Comment: Would you please share me the link to download the patch file?

Comment: It seems the download for 1.4/1.5 has been pulled from the website. I'll try to find out why.

Comment: I got it from another site https://www.byte.nl/wiki/Magento_lek_SUPEE-5346

Comment: After the patch installation I got this message.Please help me,what should do now?
The result is:
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully…
ERROR: Patch can’t be applied/reverted successfully.
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 37.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 44.
Hunk #3 FAILED at 55.
3 out of 3 hunks FAILED — saving rejects to file

Comment: You tried to apply patch 5346 which is for CE 1.6 to your 1.4 installation as it looks like from the URL. That won't work. And if you applied the correct patch it means the mentioned file is modified in your installation and couldn't be patched because of this.

Comment: right now Magento team updated the patch file.Please check the given below link

http://www.magentocommerce.com/download

Comment: Yes, 1.4/1.5 is available again and now there also is a 1.5.1.0 patch.

Comment: I tried with 5388 patch but same error is occurred.

Comment: If once you installed a patch  and after that again you try to install the same patch, it will shows this type of error.