# Patch 5994 for Magento 1.5.1.0

Tags: patches, magento-1.5

Where is the patch 5994 for `Magento 1.5.1.0` ?

I cannot find it in [the download page](https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/), only patches availables for versions `1.5.0.0`, `1.5.0.1` and `1.5.1.1`.

I think it the same case [as before](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/57543/installation-of-patch-supee-5344-for-magento-1-5-1-0) : the patch is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `Magento CE 1.5.1.1` so I guess it's just a typo with the dropdown label. Should be `SUPEE-5994 for CE 1.5.0.0, 1.5.1.0 (0.04 MB)` instead.

I ran this patch on a `Magento CE 1.5.1.0` with no errors.

The only reason why a separate patch for `Magento CE 1.5.0.1` was issued is that this version does not include a `get.php` in the root directory.